# Create Table dynamically and get back their values in jsp Page

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I am working on a project using jsp and html, in which I am adding rows in table dynamically on addRow button click. After adding the rows I am getting the values of all rows in jsp page. But its not getting the values back on jsp page as the name of the parameter is not recognized by jsp page
I am using the following code. Suggest me where i have been stuck.

HTML code:

```jsp
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            function addRow(tableID) {
                var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); 
                var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
                var element1 = document.createElement("input");
                element1.type = "text";

                element1.name = "line"+(rowCount+1);
                element1.value=""+(rowCount+1);
                cell0.appendChild(element1);
                document.getElementById("countofrows").value=table.rows.length;
            }
        </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form name="" action="myjsp.jsp">
           <table  id="receiptTable">    
               <tr>
                   <td><input tye="text" name="line1" value="0"></td>
                   <input type="hidden" name="countofrows">
               </tr>
           </table>
           <table>
               <tr>
                   <input type="button" name="addrow" onClick="addRow('receiptTable')"      value="Add Line">
               </tr>
           </table>
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Following is the JSP scriptlet code

```
<%
    int count=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("countofrows"));
    for(int i=1 ; i<=count ; i++;) {
        String value=request.getParameter("line"+i));
        out.println(" value here is"+value);
    }
%>
```

It's working fine for the default row element but getting null in case of   adding row

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<input type="hidden" name="countofrows">
```

with

```
<input type="hidden" name="countofrows" id="countofrows">
```

and try again.

Comment: Would you tell me how the form to be submitted?

Answer (score 0):

How about this one

```
   <script language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID,theForm) 
{
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); 
            var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "text";

            element1.name = "line"+(rowCount+1);
            element1.value=""+(rowCount+1);
            cell0.appendChild(element1);
            theForm.countofrows.value=table.rows.length;
}
   </script>    
   <form name="" action="myjsp.jsp">
     <table id="receiptTable">
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <input tye="text" name="line1" value="0">
             </td>
             <input type="hidden" name="countofrows" id="countofrows" >
         </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
         <tr>
             <input type="button" name="addrow" onClick="addRow('receiptTable',this.form)" value="Add Line">
         </tr>
     </table>
 </form>
```